# Save array of ObjectId in Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called `Shop` whos schema looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ShopSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  description: String,
  stock: { type: Number, default: 100 },
  latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
  longitude: { type: Number, required: true },
  image: String,
  link: String,
  tags: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Shop', ShopSchema);
```

I want to use the array `tags` to reference to another model via `ObjectId` obviously. This set up works fine when I add ids into the property via `db.shops.update({...}, {$set: {tags: ...}})` and the ids get set properly. But when I try to do it via the Express.js controller assigned to the model, nothing gets updated and there even is no error message. Here is update function in the controller:

```
// Updates an existing shop in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Shop.findById(req.params.id, function (err, shop) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!shop) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(shop, req.body);
    shop.updatedAt = new Date();
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, shop);
    });
  });
};
```

This works perfect for any other properties of the `Shop` model but just not for the tags. I also tried to set the type of the tags to string, but that didn't help.

I guess I am missing something about saving arrays in Mongoose?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your `updated` object, before the `save`?

Comment: Of course, here you go:

    `{ _id: 5483977030adcc600450db0f,
      name: 'Kunstspätkauf',
      address: 'Schlesische Str. 19, 10997 Berlin',
      latitude: 52.49861,
      longitude: 13.446149999999989,
      image: 'http://www.oushop.com/warp_sites/oushop.g6/files/Shop2.jpg',
      __v: 0,
      updatedAt: Sat Dec 06 2014 23:58:13 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time),
      createdAt: Tue Oct 22 2013 10:34:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),
      tags: [ 5483977030adcc600450db13, 5483977030adcc600450db14 ],
      stock: 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is `_.merge()` cannot handle merging arrays properly, which is the `tags` array in your case. A workaround would be adding explicit assignment of `tags` array after the merge, if it is ok to overwrite the existing tags.

```
var updated = _.merge(shop, req.body);
if (req.body.tags) {
  updated.tags = req.body.tags;
}
```

Hope this helps.. If the workaround is not sufficient you may visit `lodash` forums.